# Divide balance equally on contacts based on the total balance on account whenever account is updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I know this is not a good solution to this problem. I don't want to use inner query and I would like to get feedback on how we can improve this.

```java
public class AccountHandler {
    public static void divideAmount(List<Account> acclist){
        Integer numberofcon = 0;
        Map<Id,Decimal> mapacc = new Map<id,Decimal>();
        for(Account acc : acclist){
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue!=null){
                 mapacc.put(acc.id,acc.AnnualRevenue);
            }
           
        }
        
        List<AggregateResult> arlist = [Select count(id) cid from Contact where AccountId in :mapacc.keyset()];
        for(AggregateResult ar : arlist){
         numberofcon = (Integer)ar.get('cid');
        }
        List<Contact> conlist = [Select id,name,Amount__c,AccountId from Contact where AccountId in :mapacc.keyset() ];
        List<Contact> newlist =  new List<Contact>();
        System.debug('whats there' + conlist);
        for(Contact con : conlist){
            con.Amount__c = mapacc.get(con.AccountId) / numberofcon;
            newlist.add(con);
        }
        update newlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? What isn't working as you expect, and what are some examples (I expect result X but I see result Y)? [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Hi @DerekF, I wrote my question in summary but I don't know why it's not updated. I know this is not a good solution to this problem. I don't want to use inner query and I would like to get feedback on how we can improve this.

Comment: It looks like this will be called from a Trigger, so the key thing I would focus on would be bulkification. You should be able to get all of your Account Ids into one `Set` and query for Contacts tied to those Accounts in one query. I would make a `Map<Account, List<Id>>` where the keys are Accounts in the trigger and the List (or a Set works too) is the number of Contacts tied to the Account.

Comment: Why not use a rollup tool or build custom rollup to count the number of contacts in an account, then use a formula field to divide the balance?